# Retrieve photos on Azure

Tags: database, azure, powershell, server

I have a task to do on Azure.

On Azure, I need to get photos with a link like this :

https://picture.blob.core.windows.net/datapicture

I was given this document.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/get-azurestorageblobcontent?view=azurermps-6.13.0

The goal is to make a powershell script that allows you to retrieve photos in this path with Azure.

I don't have a key to login but a login user and password.

My connection model is, I think :

```
Login-AzureRmAccount

$SourceResourceGroupName = "...";
$SourceServerName = "...";
$Database = "...";
$ServerInstance =  "...";
$Username = "...";
$Password = "..."

$con.ConnectionString = "Server=$ServerInstance;
                        uid=$Username; 
                        pwd=$Password;
                        Database=$Database;
                        Integrated Security=False;"         
$con.Open();
```

Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: What does that mean? "I don't have a key to login but a login user and password." Blob storage authenticates either via symmetric key, AzureAD or not at all (in case of a public blob). There is no username/password basic auth

Comment: Maybe there is no user/password basic auth. I'd just like to download the image files for this link in the following path with Azure : https://picture.blob.core.windows.net/datapicture

Comment: Find a optional solution which may meet your requirement. Could you please have a check?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are trying to download file from [Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-overview). It is not working like a database.

Just as silent explained in comment, Azure Storage supports symmetric key and Azure AD authentication. Or, you can set your file to public in which way it can be accessed directly.

You used `Login-AzureRmAccount` command. So, you should be able to download a blob as following:

```
$ResourceGroup = "Jack"
$StorageAccount = "storagetest789"
$Container = "function"
Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $StorageAccount
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $Container -Blob "User1.txt" -Destination 'D:\'
```

---

**Update**

A normal storage blob URL should look like the following: `https://{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_name}`

So, you may get `$StorageAccount`, `$Container` and `$Blob` as following:

```
$UserName = '.......';
$Password = '.........';
$Secret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force;
$PsCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName, $Secret);
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $PsCred;

$ResourceGroup = '';
$URL = 'https://{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_name}';

$StorageAccount = $URL.Substring('https://'.Length,$URL.IndexOf(".")-'https://'.Length);
$Path = $URL.Substring($URL.IndexOf('.blob.core.windows.net/')+'.blob.core.windows.net/'.Length);
$Container = $Path.Substring(0,$Path.IndexOf('/'));
$Blob = $Path.Substring($Container.Length+1);

Set-AzCurrentStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $StorageAccount;
Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $Container -Blob $Blob -Destination 'D:\';
```